# Where are the network configuration files located on Solaris 11.3?

Tags: networking, configuration, solaris

On RHEL 7, network configuration files are located in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*`. Is there an equivalent configuration file location for Solaris 11.3 so I can edit network devices using the config files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link gives the network configuration files for Solaris and a summary of each one:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1453/ipconfig-12.html

Below is the essential information:

`/etc/defaultrouter`

This file contains the IP interface names of the routers that are directly connected to the network. The existence of this file in the system is optional. If the file exists, then the system is configured to support static routing.

`/etc/inet/hosts`

This file contains the IPv4 addresses in the network together with the corresponding interface names on which the addresses are configured. If you are using NIS or DNS name service, or the LDAP directory service, then the host information is stored in a different database, such as hosts.byname, that exists in the servers. For more information, see Oracle Solaris Administration: Naming and Directory Services.

`/etc/inet/netmasks`

This file contains the network number, such as 192.168.0.0, and the netmask information of that network number, such as 255.255.255.0. In a network that uses NIS or LDAP, this information is stored in a netmask database in the servers. See the netmasks(4) man page for more information.

`/etc/bootparams`

This file contains parameters that determine the boot processes for systems that are configured to boot in network client mode. For more information see Setting Up System Configuration Modes. The file is the basis for the creation of the bootparams database that the name service uses if you are not using the local files mode. To obtain specific information about the content and format of this file, refer to the bootparams(4) man page.

`/etc/ethers`

This file associates hostnames with their MAC addresses. The file is the basis for the creation of an ethers database for use in the network where systems are configured as network clients. For more information, see the ethers(4) man page.

`/etc/inet/networks`

This file associates network names and network numbers. Comments can also be added to further clarify each entry in the database. This file enables applications to use and display the network names instead of network numbers. For example, the netstat program uses the information in this database to produce status tables. All the subnetworks that connect to the local network through routers must be included in this file. For more information, see the networks(4) man page.

`/etc/inet/protocols`

This file lists the TCP/IP protocols that are installed on your system as well as their protocol numbers. This file seldom requires any administration. For more information, see the protocols(4) man page.

`/etc/inet/services`

This file lists the names of TCP and UDP services and their well-known port numbers. The list is used by programs that call network services. Generally, this file does not require any administration. For more information, see the services(4) man page.

Answer (score 3):

Network interfaces in Solaris 11 are configured using the dladm and ipadm commands, not editing files directly.  See the man pages for those.

Comment: I agree with you, but want to add path to this file: **/etc/ipadm/ipadm-DefaultFixed.conf** . Normally you should not edit it by hands, but this knowledge may help for maintenance or recovery.